# Issue with echo in shell script

Tags: shell, echo

getting issue with echo output.

```html
line=table_name

echo "SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT_TYPE LIKE '%character%' THEN 'replace(replace(replace('||ATTNAME||',''\'',''\\''),''"'',''\"''),''|'',''\|'') as '||ATTNAME||',' ELSE ATTNAME||',' END FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN WHERE NAME = '$line' ORDER BY ATTNUM;"
```

Output I am looking for something like below:

```html
SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT_TYPE LIKE '%character%'
                  THEN 'REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('||ATTNAME||',''\'',''\\''),''"'',''\"''),''|'',''\|'') AS '||ATTNAME||','
                  ELSE ATTNAME||','
              END
FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN WHERE NAME IN ('table_name')
ORDER BY ATTNUM;
```

But getting there error as

```html
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Comment: Same error with the below : echo "SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT_TYPE LIKE '%character%' THEN 'replace(replace(replace('||ATTNAME||',''\'',''\\''),''\"'',''\\"''),''|'',''\|'') as '||ATTNAME||',' ELSE ATTNAME||',' END FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN WHERE NAME = '$line' ORDER BY ATTNUM;"

Comment: Why have you added more unescaped double quotes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in your string

Try

```
echo "SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT_TYPE LIKE '%character%' THEN 'replace(replace(replace('||ATTNAME||',''\'',''\\''),''\"'',''\\\"''),''|'',''\|'') as '||ATTNAME||',' ELSE ATTNAME||',' END FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN WHERE NAME = '$line' ORDER BY ATTNUM;"
```

Note that to print an escape you have to escape the escape.

e.g

If you want `\"`
You need to type `\\\"`

Comment: Ideally we need 4 backslash for the first replacement. Otherwise it is good.echo "SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT_TYPE LIKE '%character%' 
                  THEN 'replace(replace(replace('||ATTNAME||',''\'',''\\\\''),''\"'',''\\\"''),''|'',''\|'') as '||ATTNAME||',' 
      ELSE ATTNAME||',' 
     END 
FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN 
WHERE NAME = '$line' ORDER BY ATTNUM;"